# How to run Terminal commands from cocoa app?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, terminal, process

I have problems running a Terminal command from a Cocoa Application. 
The input for the Terminal is real easy: `/Users/.../Csvmidi </Users/.../test.csv> /Users/.../Melody.mid`
These are three inputs- three actual paths - are just written in a row and seperated by a spac: the first "Csvmidi" runs a Unix Application which converts the test.csv to an actual hearable MIDI file. Through the terminal it works perfectly...

I just don't get it to work via a Cocoa Application.

```
        let process = Process()
        process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh/")
        process.arguments = [lblCsvmidi.stringValue,"<"+lblURL.stringValue+">",lblMidi.stringValue]
    //I saved the URL of the UNIX program, test.csv and Melody.mid in a lable just to be sure.
    //lblCsvmidi --> URL of Csvmidi UNIX program
    //lblURL --> URL of test.csv
    //lblMidi --> URL of Melody.mid


        print(lblCsvmidi.stringValue,"<" + lblURL.stringValue + ">",lblMidi.stringValue) 
    // this print command was only made to check the arguments in the terminal if they would work --> they do


        process.terminationHandler = { (process) in
            print("\ndidFinish: \(!process.isRunning)")
        }
        do {

          try process.run()
        } catch {}
```

When I run the code it gives me either the error of an `75: unmatched"`, but actually there isn't a quotation mark in the command - or I get "permission denied" errors.

I tried several bin folders like ( I really tried almost every possible):
 - /bin/zsh
 - /bin/csh
 - /bin/ksh
 - ...
What am i doing wrong --> I haven't found information in other Questions here and the Process, NSTask and Bundle informations from Apple haven't helped me so far.

Thanks!!

Comment: Doing this via the shell is really roundabout. You can just go "straight to the source" and use the `NSWorkspace` APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

The following runs without error on my system:

```
import Cocoa 

let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh/")

var args : [String]!
args = []
args.append("-c")
args.append("open '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp'")
process.arguments = args
process.terminationHandler = { (process) in
  print("\ndidFinish: \(!process.isRunning)")
}
do {
   try process.run()
 } catch {}

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```

The strings after "-c" would depend on what you are trying to accomplish.